# Why when importing widgets from a different file it don't show?

Tags: flutter

FLUTTER: I am trying to separate my main widget in different ones, so the app is faster and the code is better. I have the main file (invoice.dart), and in there I am importing two different widgets from different files:

There is a huge space between them two, how to remove it?

MAIN FILE:

```
   class Invoice extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  InvoiceState createState() => InvoiceState();
}

class InvoiceState extends State<Invoice> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Container(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            child: Column(children: <Widget>[
              Expanded(
                child: TopPart(),
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: RecentTransactions(),
              )
            ])));
  }
}
```

OTHER WIDGET:

```
class RecentTransactionsState extends State<RecentTransactions> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Expanded(
          child: Container(
            height: 300,
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(21.0),
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
              children: <Widget>[
                Text(
                  'RECENT TRANSACTIONS',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.black,
                    fontSize: 17.0,
                  ),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: ListView(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Transaction(
                        concept: 'July Rent',
                        transactionAmout: '800.00',
                        transactionDate: '01 Jul 2020',
                        transactionInfo: 'Co-living',
                        transactionType: TransactionType.sent,
                      ),
                      Transaction(
                        concept: '6h Co-working space',
                        transactionAmout: '60.00',
                        transactionDate: '26 Jun 2019',
                        transactionInfo: 'Co-working',
                        transactionType: TransactionType.received,
                      ),
                      Transaction(
                        concept: 'Laundry',
                        transactionAmout: '20.0',
                        transactionDate: '19 Jun 2019',
                        transactionInfo: 'Extra Services',
                        transactionType: TransactionType.pending,
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

OTHER WIDGET:

```
body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
                  color: Color(0xFF89C9B8),
                  child: Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Column(
                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                            children: <Widget>[
                              Text(
                                'Hey (name),',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 25.0,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                              ),
                              SizedBox(height: 12.0),
                              Text(
                                'Those are all your invoices',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 20.0, color: Colors.white70),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                          Container(
                              height: 90.0,
                              width: 90.0,
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                shape: BoxShape.circle,
                                image: DecorationImage(
                                    fit: BoxFit.fill,
                                    image: AssetImage('assets/img/woman.png')),
                              )),
                        ],
                      ),
                      // SizedBox(
                      //   height: 15.0,
                      // ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you show content of class `TopPart`?

Comment: The error means that your widget is too big for the screen. A quick solution could be to put everything in a `SingleChildScrollView`. If you don't want this: What does `TopPart` look like?

Comment: Try it:    children: [
                   child: Column(children: <Widget>[
                   Expanded( child: TopPart(),)
                ]))
              ],

Comment: Show other files as well to more clarify your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used:

```
alignment: Alignment.center,
            child: Column(children: <Widget>[
              SizedBox(
                height: 150.0,
                child: Expanded(
                  child: TopPart(),
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 2.0),
              Expanded(
                child: RecentTransactions(),
              )
            ])));
  }
```